# Segmentation fault: 11 when trying to print linked list

Tags: c, pointers, null, segmentation-fault

I'm fairly new to C and I know I'm probably doing something wrong with pointers but I just can't seem pinpoint what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the structs and functions for the linked list:

```c
// node structure
struct Node {
    int val;
    struct Node* next;
};

// singly linked list structure
struct LinkedList {
    int size;
    struct Node* head;
} LinkedList = {0, NULL};


// insert at head function
void InsertHead(struct LinkedList* list, int val) {
    struct Node* node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->val = val;
    node->next = list->head;
    list->head = node;
    list->size++;
}

// print values in list
void PrintList(struct LinkedList* list) {
    struct Node* node = list->head;

    while (node != NULL) {
        printf("%d, ", node->val);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

When I try to call **PrintList** with the following code:

```c
// main function
int main() {
    struct LinkedList* mylist = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    InsertHead(mylist, 4);
    InsertHead(mylist, 3);
    InsertHead(mylist, 1);

    // printf("%d, ", mylist->head->val);
    // printf("%d, ", mylist->head->next->val);
    // printf("%d, ", mylist->head->next->next->val);
    // printf("\n");
    PrintList(mylist);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the error `Segmentation fault: 11`

When I run remove the call to PrintList function and uncomment the printf statements, I get the desired output:

```
1,3,4,
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You failed to initialise `mylist`.  Allocating it with `calloc` instead of `malloc` would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never intialize the `struct LinkedList` you allocate at the top of `main()`.

So when you're walking the list to print it, after the three elements you inserted explicitly, the `next` field of the last one will contain whichever garbage was in the `head` field of the original `LinkedList` when it was allocated.

To fix this, you can either allocate it with `calloc` instead (which explicitly zeros out the allocated memory befor it's given to you), or write a helper function that both allocates *and* explicitly initializes a `struct LinkedList`.

Comment: That makes sense, but what confuses me now is why did my printf statements work in the first place?

Comment: @JayMody: Because they never need to _follow_ the garbage `next` pointer at the end of the list. You're hardcoding that the list has exactly three element, instead of comparing each `next` pointer to `NULL` to see if you've reached the end.

Comment: If that's true, then when I try `if (mylist->head->next->next->next == NULL) printf("hey");` why don't get an error?

Comment: @JayMody: This _reads_ the garbage pointer (and either prints `hey` or it doesn't); it's not trying to _dereference_ it.